# Find a Cut-Set in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, cut

consider a triangle graph G with V = {a,b,c} and E = {ab,bc,ca}. If edge subset S= {ab,bc} are removed then we get edge ac left. My question **is S a valid cutset** ( it partitions the G into two vertex subsets {b} and {a,c})

Note: a cut is a partition of the vertices of a graph into two disjoint subsets. The cut-set of the cut is the set of edges whose end points are in different subsets of the partition.

Comment: yes, you are kinda asking the obviuos in a manner that you already know the answer... i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

*{ab, bc}* is a cut-set because it induces a cut. The cut induced by *{ab, bc}* is *( {a,c} , {b} )*.

I'll clarify the definitions:

- A cut is a partition of the graph vertices. For example, *( {a,c} , {b} )* is a cut because each vertex in the graph belongs to exactly one of the two sets.
- A cut-set of a cut (S,T) is the following set of edges: *{uv | u in S and v in T}*. For example, the cut-set of *( {a,c} , {b} )* is *{ab, bc}*.
- A set E of edges is a cut set if and only if there exists a cut of which E is its cut-set. In your example, the set *{ab}* is not a cut set because you can't determine whether the vertex c belongs to S or T. The set *{ab,bc,ca}* is not a cut-set because you can easily prove by contradiction that there's no cut for which *{ab,bc,ca}* is its cut-set.